# SQL contains issue in stored procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Trying out the contains verb on a DB i'm making and I want to know the issue with this syntax

```
create or replace PROCEDURE past_event_check
as
BEGIN
SELECT  event_description from past_events
where Contains (event_description, 'Club');

END;
```

It says Compilation failed,line 5 (04:29:41)
PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operatorCompilation failed,line 4 (04:29:41)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like the below

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE past_event_check
    as
     l_event_desc past_events.event_description%TYPE;
     BEGIN
     SELECT  event_description into l_event_desc from past_events
    where Contains (event_description, 'Club',1) > 0;
     dbms_output.put_line(l_event_desc);
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

`CONTAINS` is Oracle Text. See this example:

```
SQL> create table test as select * From emp;

Table created.

SQL> select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal from test
  2  where contains(ename, 'king') > 0;
select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal from test
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10599: column is not indexed


SQL>
```

Right; Oracle Text - column has to be indexed, but not by any index type:

```
SQL> create index i1 on test(ename) indextype is ctxsys.context;

Index created.

SQL> select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal from test
  2  where contains(ename, 'king') > 0;

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10       7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000

SQL>
```

OK, prerequisites are now met.

If you want to move such a query into PL/SQL (which a stored procedure is), it requires you to fetch data **into** something - a variable. Declare it and use in `select` statement:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_ename in test.ename%type) is
  2    l_job test.job%type;          --> declared is here
  3  begin
  4    select job
  5      into l_job                  --> used is here
  6      from test
  7      where contains(ename, par_ename) > 0;
  8    dbms_output.put_line(par_ename || ' works as ' || l_job);
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    p_test('king');
  3  end;
  4  /
king works as PRESIDENT

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Depending on what you really are doing, this might need to be fixed as there's *danger* of various errors (such as `TOO_MANY_ROWS` returned by query, etc.).

---

If you didn't actually want to use Oracle Text, then look at other options: `instr` and `like`:

```
SQL> select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal from test
  2  where instr(ename, 'KING') > 0;

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10       7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000

SQL> select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal from test
  2  where ename like '%KING%';

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10       7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This really helped me to understand it a bit more